# How to update cordova plugins version

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have used the older version of cordova plugins in hybrid mobile application project.

Now, i will update the cordova plugins version using command prompt.

I have used the single code for **cordova-check-plugins --update=auto --force**

to auto update the plugins version.

And i have clear the cache in my project.

But the plugins not update and showing the error message for

```
Checking remote versions... |Failed to check npm registry for plugin 'cordova-op
en-native-settings'
Error: Command failed: npm view "https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-
settings.git" version
npm ERR! Invalid package.json
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\administrator.WBCDNS.000\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2
017-09-22T05_00_21_306Z-debug.log
```

and also show the Error for Plugins are outdated.

Tell me how to update the cordova plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

> `npm ERR! Invalid package.json`

If you validate the package.json for that repo using http://package-json-validator.com/ (enter the github repo as `https://github.com/guyromb/Cordova-open-native-settings`), then it tells you why:

Results:

```
{
  "valid": false,
  "errors": [
    "contributors field should have name",
    "contributors field should have name",
    "contributors field should have name",
    "contributors field should have name",
    "contributors field should have name",
    "contributors field should have name",
    "Type for field engines, was expected to be object, not object"
  ],
  "recommendations": [
    "Missing optional field: dependencies"
  ]
}
```

The author has mistakenly used the `username` key instead of `name` in the `contributors` list.

Therefore the `cordova-check-plugins` tool cannot update the plugin, because the `npm view` command it uses to check the current version fails due to the invalid package.json.